# What is the expectation value of the minimum 'distance' between two random 64-bit numbers out of a set of N?

Tags: probability, birthday, hash-function

Assume we have a set of N random integer numbers in the interval `[0, 2^64>` (or equivalent, consider N randomly chosen corners (vectors) of a 64-dimensional hypercube with side 1).

Find the two numbers that have the smallest number of bits that are different (or equivalent, find the square of the minimum distance between two of those N corners). Lets call this number of different bits 'the distance'. This distance can be zero (two numbers are equal / two of the vectors are the same). It can not be 64 when N is larger than 2.

Empirically I determined that for N = 39800, the (expected) minimum distance is near 9. That is; with 39800 numbers/vectors you can form 39800 * 39799 = 1584000200 pairs - and most of the time I found one or more pairs had only 9 different bits while all other pairs had more than 9 different bits. Sometimes this minimum was 10 or 8 or even 7, but on average I'd say 9.

Can someone derive a function that gives the expectation value for the minimum distance as function of N? For example, such a function could give `f(39800) = 8.438...`.

Note that this problem is remotely related to the birthday paradox: having 39800 people and 2^64 birthdays - you could calculate what the chance is that two people have the same birthday; but that corresponds to asking what is the chance that the distance is zero. Instead I want to know what the expectation value is for the minimum distance (the chance that that is zero is still very very small).

Comment: Consider a bit vector of size $64$. How many 1-bit different vectors does it have? How many 2-bit different vectors does it have? and so on. Once you answer these your problem is almost done.

Comment: It has `64!/(n! * (64-n)!)` vectors that are n-bit different. How does that bring me closer to the answer?

Comment: Once you count each set of distances, then the rest is probability. Actually, the result should be close to 32.

Comment: It is only close to 32 for really small N. For moderately small N, like 39800, it is around 9. Are you sure you understand the question?

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104698/the-expected-minimum-hamming-distance-within-a-set-of-randomly-selected-binary-s

Comment: @user51547 Who is this Hamming and why is he using his name for my distance? :D Haha. I guess I should be proud that I called it a "distance" though ;). Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are in fact ${39800 \choose 2}= 792000100$ pairs (half your number, because of duplicates). Let's call this $m$.
- The probability that a particular  distance is $n$ or less is $p_n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{64 \choose i}2^{-i}$.
- For $n=9$ this is about $p_9=1.77\times 10^{-9}$ and $p_9 m \approx 1.4$ so we are talking about opposite orders of magnitude.
- The distances are not quite independent but there are so many pairs that they are close to independent.
- Assuming independence, the probability that any of $m$ distances are $n$ or less is $1-(1-p_n)^m$
- So the probability that the minimum distance is exactly $n$ is $(1-p_{n-1})^{m}-(1-p_n)^m$ which give the following probabilities for the minimum distance

  ```
   n    prob. minimum distance is n
   2    0.0000001
   3    0.0000018
   4    0.0000273
   5    0.0003273
   6    0.0032126
   7    0.0262251
   8    0.1679132
   9    0.5563657
  10    0.2455585
  11    0.0003685
  ```

with a median and mode of $9$ and mean about $9.01$.

This seems broadly  consistent with your observation of *"most of the time I found one or more pairs had only 9 different bits while all other pairs had more than 9 different bits. Sometimes this minimum was 10 or 8 or even 7, but on average I'd say 9."*

Comment: Thank you! I had given up on anyone answering this ;). What I needed this for is for a hash function that I wrote that is intended to hash one or more heap allocation pointers (see https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/pointer_hash.h). While normally a hash function just mangles all bits equally, pointers to allocations are often close together and have a strong correlation in alignment; which translates into that the entropy of the low bits, but not the lowest bits, are more important than the high bits. So, you want to especially preserve the entropy of those bits of the (two)

Comment: inputs in the answer. In the extreme case, you could output 64bits where the first 32bits are the low 32bits of input 1 and the second 32bits are the low 32bits of input 2, preserving 100% of the entropy of low 32bits - but none of the high 32bits of the inputs.

Comment: In order to test my hash function, I generated 200 "pointer" values that are super correlated (close together and all at equal distance) and then calculate the hash of each of the 200 * 199 pairs (in this case the order matters: the resulting hash is different with swapped inputs) = 39800 hash values. And what I want then is that all those hash values are "indistinguishable" from random values: they should be all maximal different. My test program, see https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils-testsuite/blob/master/src/pointer_hash_test.cxx, shows that their minimum distance is around 9 bits.

Comment: So, then I was wondering if that corresponds with the theoretical optimum. Of course I could very this without the formulas you provided me with, which is what I resorted to: I just regenerated true random numbers and then looked at their distance. The shocking thing is now: my hash function performs *better* than random numbers :D. I have no idea why or if that is even possible; but perhaps it is. My ultimate goal was to write a hash function that literally gives a different weight to different bits in terms of preserving entrophy - but well. Too much to do and I moved on with other things.